# Cannot connect to VMWare virtual machine through NAT

Tags: networking, ssh, vmware

I am currently reading Yahoo's Hadoop tutorial in [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html). I have installed VMWare player and running a virtual machine, as instructed by the tutorial. However, I cannot connect to my Guest machine from Host, no matter what I try.

The default is NAT mode. When I try to run `ifconfig`, I get the following address:

```
192.168.187.128
```

Attempting to ping it from within the guest results in success, but any attempt to ping it from the host results in failure.  I am using Windows 7 (Host) and Ubuntu (Guest).

---

I tried changing the networking mode of VMWare to "Host-only". In this case, it looks like there is a failure in the initialization of the netowrking part of the virtual machine:

```
DHCPRequest of 192.168.187.128 on eth10 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPRequest of 192.168.187.128 on eth10 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPDiscover on eth10 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
DHCPDiscover on eth10 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
DHCPDiscover on eth10 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
DHCPDiscover on eth10 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
DHCPDiscover on eth10 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
DHCPDiscover on eth10 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
DHCPDiscover on eth10 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
No DHCPOffers received

Trying recorder lease 192.168.187.128
PING 192.168.187.2 (192.168.187.2) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.187.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmited, 0 recieved, +1 errors, 100% packet loss ,time 0ms
```

And once again, pinging from the host fails.
Using "Bridged" mode results in similar scenario.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by switching to VirtualBox and selecting the "Virtual Box Host Only Ethernet adapter".

In order to import the .vmdk file from VMWare, one needs to create a new Virtual Machine and select the file as Hard Drive.

Answer (score 3):

I've run into similar issues when setting up domains. By default Windows 7 is set to reject PING requests as well as other requests. Depending on your Linux distribution it may be set to reject as well. (but doesn't seen to be in this case if I'm reading your post correctly)

If you really want to see a response from Windows you need to take down the firewall (Not advised but for the purpose of testing this is fine). Go into Windows Firewall with Advanced Security, then turn off the corresponding firewall for your network (or all of them if you can't figure it out).

As another option, you can create an exception for PINGs in the inbound/outbound rules.

Bridged mode has the VMware client "share" the network connection with the host and it acts as if it is a machine on the same LAN. It requests an IP address and everything. Then communication between the two "machines" goes through your router.
(http://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_bridged_ws.html)

By using NAT mode, VMware uses your host PC as a "router" of sorts and assigns it an IP address inside that LAN. So all communication is direct in this case. But it actually does do full translation of IP addresses/everything when attempting to access outside the network (can access internet).
(http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_nat.html)

Host mode creates a direct connection between the two computers that cannot go beyond that. By default no DHCP is enabled so you need to set that up manually.

Any should work for your purposes but it's important to be aware of the differences in how messages are transferred and IP addresses are assigned.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem: all pings from my Win7 host to my Ubuntu guest (where the guest was using NAT) would time out.
In my case, the reason was that my host had a **VPN connection** open (virtual private network),
so all my pinging was forwarded to outside my machine 
rather than staying within the NAT zone.

Once I turned off the VPN, everything worked as intended.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I will not be able to check it, thus unable to rate it.

Comment: Sorry but OMGOMGOMGOMGOMGOMG THIS WORKED!!! THANK YOU!!!!!!!! I went almost crazy because I read so many things about people being able to easily connect and I just did not.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems, and nothing worked. Then, I read this page and followed the instructions, and I am now able to copy files back and forth from my windows directory to a directory in the virtual machine. I mounted a directory using these instructions:

http://blog.data-miners.com/2009/11/getting-started-with-hadoop-and.html#comment-form

Comment: Please, provide quotation of significant points from link you provided (in case link will go dead -> data will be accessible here)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I will not be able to check it, thus unable to rate it.

Answer (score 0):

on VMWare go to virtual network and remove all of them. The problem should now be gone because VMWare will now use a file `vmnat.exe` for connecting VM to internet.
If this not worked, create a new virual network. Also remember to do some restart between this process as it has some benefits .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I will not be able to check it, thus unable to rate it.

Answer (score 0):

The sense of using NAT is to protect the guest from inbount access. If you want to access your VM from within your physical LAN go for bridged.